# How to make realy exclusive touch for a view inside uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm going to show a chart inside a scroll view that when I am dragging on a chart, scroll view doesn't work.

I've already tried to use `isExclusiveTouch` on my view but doesn't work as my expected.

When I am going to touch on a chart and drag my finger on it to display other values, scroll view catch my touch event and scrolling happen.

Comment: are you using this library ? https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: No i am using [core plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) but my question is generic and not depend on library. @BenRockey

Comment: Have you tried setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of your chart to `false`?

Comment: @Malik Yes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. Hope this helps.


If you want disable `UIScrollView` scrolling you should override `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` method. Detect which view touched and if you want to stop scrolling `return false` otherwise you must call `super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)`.

In my case I defined a constant variable in my class and used it as tag in a view that i want to disable scrolling on it.

```swift
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

    static let EXCEPTION_FOR_SCROLLING = 1

    var exceptionViews: [UIView]?

    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let view = gestureRecognizer.view {
            if shouldCancelTouch(view, gestureRecognizer) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    private func shouldCancelTouch(_ view: UIView, _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if (exceptionViews?.contains(view) ?? false) || view.tag == CustomScrollView.EXCEPTION_FOR_SCROLLING {
            return true
        } else {
            for i in 0..<view.subviews.count {
                if view.subviews[i].frame.contains(gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)) {
                    if shouldCancelTouch(view.subviews[i], gestureRecognizer) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }

}
```